# How to derive one formula of projection from another

Tags: linear-algebra

The projection onto the subspace (hyperplane)

$$H:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\langle a,x\rangle=0\}$$

is given by $$P_{H}(x)=x-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\|a\|^2}a. \tag 1$$ and also the projection onto any subspace $V$ (including $H$) can be defined by

$$P_V(x)=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T(x) \tag 2$$

where $A$ is the a matrix whose columns are spanning set for the subspace $V$ who are linearly independent. My question is how can we get (1) from (2)? I appreciate any help  and if possible if some one can show me that as I am not able to make an argue about that. I know for the subspace (hyperplane) $H$ is of dimension $n-1$ and I can understand the derivation of (1). Also I can understand how (2) is been derived but I am struglling in getting from (2) to (1). Thanks to every one contribute in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal projection $P$ onto any subspace of a finite-dimensional space is $P=I-Q$, where $I$ is the identity operator and $Q$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the subspace.  Thus the projection $P$ onto an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional space is $P=I-Q$, where $Q$ is the projection onto the $1$-dimensional orthogonal complement of the $(n-1)$-dimensional space.  The orthogonal complement of the space $\{x\in\mathbb R^n : \langle a,x\rangle=0\}$ is the space spanned by the vector $a$. Thus you need to apply $(2)$ in the case where the matrix $A$ has just one column, which is $a$.  In that case the matrix $A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $1$.  And in that case, the matrix $A^T A$ is the scalar $\|a\|^2$, so multiplying by its inverse is just dividing by that scalar.  Multiplication by a scalar commutes with matrix multiplication, so we have
$$
A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T x = \frac{AA^T x}{\|a\|^2}\quad(\text{when $A$ has just one column}).
$$
And in that case where $A$ has just one column, which is $a$, we also have $A^T x = \langle a,x\rangle$. Thus $(A^T A)^{-1} A^T x$ becomes the scalar $\dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\|a\|^2}$.  And again, multiplying by a scalar commutes with multiplying matrices, so $A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T x$ is $\dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\|a\|^2} A = \dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\|a\|^2} a$.

Comment: Big thanks Michael but I did not understand the last statement when saying "And again, multiplying by a scalar commutes....". Could you make it more clear to me please? and also we have $x-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle}{||a||^2}a$ in our original formula so where is $x-$ gone? Thanks.

Comment: The statement about commuting meant that $A\dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\|a\|^2} = \dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\|a\|^2}A$.  As for where the $x-\cdots$ went, notice that I said $P=I-Q$ and then I worked on finding $Q$.  After you find $Q$, you can write $Px=(I-Q)x=x-Qx$, and there you have $x-\cdots$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Big thanks again Michael. If you are happy to help more, can you explain to me the following: if we have a subspace (affine subspace) which is the intersection of hyperplanes, how can we derive the projection formula for projection onto that affine subspace? In other words how to link between the alternating projections, the projection onto hyperplanes, and the projection onto affine subspace? What is the link between the previous formulas above we discussed and the alternating projections?Thanks.